# EHCache issue with localCacheEnabled and Cache replicated between apps

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish, ehcache, terracotta

I'm getting an exception when trying to access to my app that is making me crazy. I tried too many variants but none of them worked. The exception is:

```
[2014-06-27T09:57:07.058+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1403855827058] [levelValue: 800] [[ 
  ERROR 27/06/2014 09:57:07.055 [jk-connector(2)]  
find failed: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Uncaught exception in setPinned() - Pinning is not supported when local cache is disabled]] 

[2014-06-27T09:57:07.081+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=Thread-4] [timeMillis: 1403855827081] [levelValue: 1000] [[ 
  org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Uncaught exception in setPinned() - Pinning is not supported when local cache is disabled 
    at net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.regions.EhcacheTransactionalDataRegion.put(EhcacheTransactionalDataRegion.java:151) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.regions.EhcacheTransactionalDataRegion.put(EhcacheTransactionalDataRegion.java:126) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.strategy.AbstractReadWriteEhcacheAccessStrategy.putFromLoad(AbstractReadWriteEhcacheAccessStrategy.java:93) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.nonstop.NonstopAwareEntityRegionAccessStrategy.putFromLoad(NonstopAwareEntityRegionAccessStrategy.java:180) 
    at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:179) 
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:877) 
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:752) 
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) 
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232) 
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2161) 
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2121) 
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:118) 
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1597) 
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306) 
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:328) 
    (...)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) 
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193) 
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) 
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189) 
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) 
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54) 
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562) 
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77) 
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:873) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378) 
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213) 
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171) 
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145) 
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92) 
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673) 
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174) 
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) 
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260) 
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) 
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Uncaught exception in setPinned() - Pinning is not supported when local cache is disabled 
    at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.store.ClusteredSafeStore.setPinned(ClusteredSafeStore.java:212) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.setPinned(Cache.java:4231) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.regions.EhcacheTransactionalDataRegion.put(EhcacheTransactionalDataRegion.java:141) 
    ... 70 more
```

The application is deployed on a Glassfish 4 Server on host "front" and the Terracotta Server is on host "back".

The ehcache.xml file on the application is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache-2.6.6.xsd"
         updateCheck="false" monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true" name="hibernate-cache">

    <!-- Replicated caches between applications / ehcache servers -->
    <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
        properties="peerDiscovery=manual,
        rmiUrls=//127.0.0.1:40001/common_objects_region|//127.0.0.1:40001/org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache|//127.0.0.1:40001/org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"/>

    <cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
        properties="hostName=127.0.0.1, port=40001, socketTimeoutMillis=2000"/>


    <terracottaConfig url="back:9510" />


    <defaultCache
            maxElementsInMemory="100"
            maxElementsOnDisk="1000"
            statistics="true"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="43200"
            timeToLiveSeconds="86400"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">

               <cacheEventListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory" listenFor="all" />
               <terracotta clustered="true" consistency="eventual" localCacheEnabled="true" />
               <persistence strategy="distributed" />

    </defaultCache>

    <cache
        name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
        statistics="true"
        maxElementsInMemory="5000"
        maxElementsOnDisk="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="43200"
        timeToLiveSeconds="86400"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
           <cacheEventListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory" listenFor="all"/>
           <terracotta clustered="true" consistency="eventual" localCacheEnabled="true" />
           <persistence strategy="distributed" />
    </cache>

    <cache
        name="org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache"
        statistics="true"
        maxElementsInMemory="5000"
        maxElementsOnDisk="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="43200"
        timeToLiveSeconds="86400"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
            <cacheEventListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory" listenFor="all"/>
            <terracotta clustered="true" consistency="eventual" localCacheEnabled="true" />
            <persistence strategy="distributed" />
    </cache>

    <cache name="common_objects_region"
           statistics="true"
           maxElementsInMemory="100000"
           maxElementsOnDisk="250000"
           eternal="false"
           timeToIdleSeconds="43200"
           timeToLiveSeconds="86400"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
           <cacheEventListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory" listenFor="all" />           
            <!-- <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"
                                   properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=true,
                                               maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000"/>-->
           <terracotta clustered="true" consistency="eventual" localCacheEnabled="true" />
           <persistence strategy="distributed" />
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

And the tc-config.xml file on "back" is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
All content copyright Terracotta, Inc., unless otherwise indicated. All rights reserved.
-->

<tc:tc-config xmlns:tc="http://www.terracotta.org/config"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.terracotta.org/schema/terracotta-6.xsd">

  <!-- Configuracion de high-availability -->
  <tc-properties>
    <property name="l1.healthcheck.l2.ping.enabled" value="true" />
    <property name="l1.healthcheck.l2.ping.idletime" value="10000" />
    <property name="l1.healthcheck.l2.ping.interval" value="2000" />
    <property name="l1.healthcheck.l2.ping.probes" value="5" />
    <property name="l1.healthcheck.l2.socketConnect" value="true" />
    <property name="l1.healthcheck.l2.socketConnectTimeout" value="20" />
    <property name="l1.healthcheck.l2.socketConnectCount" value="10" />

    <!-- Client reconnection properties -->
    <property name="l2.l1reconnect.enabled" value="true" />
    <property name="l2.l1reconnect.timeout.millis" value="2000" />
    <property name="l2.healthcheck.l1.ping.enabled" value="true" />
    <property name="l2.healthcheck.l1.ping.idletime" value="10000" />
    <property name="l2.healthcheck.l1.ping.interval" value="2000" />
    <property name="l2.healthcheck.l1.ping.probes" value="5" />
    <property name="l2.healthcheck.l1.socketConnect" value="true" />
    <property name="l2.healthcheck.l1.socketConnectTimeout" value="20" />
    <property name="l2.healthcheck.l1.socketConnectCount" value="10" />
  </tc-properties>


  <!-- Tell DSO where the Terracotta server can be found; 
       See 
       - Terracotta Configuration Guide and Reference 
       - About Terracotta Configuration Files
       for additional information. -->
  <servers>
    <server host="back" name="cache">
      <dso-port>9510</dso-port>
      <jmx-port>9520</jmx-port>
      <data>/opt/terracotta/server-data</data>
      <logs>/var/log/terracotta/server-logs</logs>
      <statistics>/opt/terracotta/server-statistics</statistics>
      <dso>
        <client-reconnect-window>15</client-reconnect-window>
        <persistence>
          <mode>permanent-store</mode>
        </persistence>
        <garbage-collection>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
          <verbose>false</verbose>
          <interval>7200</interval> <!-- está en segundos -->
        </garbage-collection>
      </dso>
      <l2-group-port bind="0.0.0.0">9530</l2-group-port>
      <data-backup>/opt/terracotta/data-backup</data-backup>
      <index>/opt/terracotta/server-data/index</index>
    </server>
  </servers>
</tc:tc-config>
```

These files are working perfectly on localhost where I have both Glassfish and Terracotta Server on same machine. In addition, this configuration works nice on another host which both Glassfish and Terracotta Server on same machine too.
I tried to change the hostname on the config files by the IP of the host but the exception remains.

So many questions:
What is it wrong in these config files?
Do I need to have the Terracotta Server on same machine where is Glassfish installed?
Am I missing some configuration options for this configuration?

Thanks.

EDIT: I tried using my developer Glassfish Server with "back" Terracotta Server and I got the same exception.

UPDATE: If I disable Second Level Cache the application works fine and retrieves the info from Terracota Server but I've got no local cache and it's too slow.

Comment: SOLVED: After testing the same configuration on other server I noticed the problem it's the "back" server itself. The app works nice with Terracotta Server on another server running this same configuration.